# Confusion About Inductive (Direct) Limits in Rordam's C$^{*}$-Algebra Book

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> I am reading through Rordam's C$^{*}$-algebra book and I think I am
>   misunderstanding something. On page 92, Rordam defines Inductive
>   limits in an arbitrary category as follows.

[image]

> He goes on to show that the uniqueness of the map $\lambda\colon A\to B$ actually implies that there is a unique *isomorphism*
>   $\lambda\colon A\to B$ making (6.4) commute. So, applying this to the
>   category of C$^{*}$-algebras, I assumed this to mean that there is a
>   unique isometric $*$-isomorphism $\lambda\colon A\to B$, provided that
>   $(B, \{\lambda_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty})$ is a system as given in (ii).
>   However, I think I am really not understanding something here because
>   on page 94, Rordam has the following proposition.

[image]

> If my understanding was correct (which it obviously isn't) then
>   $\lambda$ as in 6.2.4. would be an isomorphism and, hence, a
>   bijection. But the way the proposition is phrased, it is clear that
>   this is not always the case. I would really appreciate if someone
>   would help me understand what is happening here.
>
> Thank you.

Comment: The point is that in $6.2.2$ we assume that $A $ and $B $ satisfy the properties of "being an inductive limit" of the same inductive system. Thus, both $A $ and $B $ enjoy the universal property, which is $(ii) $. This  enables you to construct maps which are inverses to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique morphism you find has not to be an isomorphism. Trivial examples are easily constructed. Take for example $A_n = \mathbb C$ with the identity as connecting map and $B = M_2(\mathbb C)$, where you map $\mathbb C $ as diagonal into $M_2(\mathbb C)$.

That gives you a map from the limit $\mathbb C$ into $M_2(\mathbb C)$ which clearly cannot be an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now. In $6.2.2$, the object $B$ need not be an inductive limit of the sequence (since it itself may not satisfy condition (ii)). If $B$ is an inductive limit, then $\lambda$ will be an isomorphism. In your counterexample, $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ is not the inductive limit of the sequence and this is why $\lambda$ is not an isomorphism. Is this correct?

Comment: $B$ is also an inductive limit but of another sequence, yes. If you want to know when two inductive limits are isomorphic, there is for example the famous "Intertwining Argument" of Elliot, see also http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1991-113-04/S0002-9939-1991-1087472-1/S0002-9939-1991-1087472-1.pdf.